# Export to *.txt with specific Font

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I need to export from **sql server** to *.txt. But i want my export to be with specific Font.Example I need my txt file to have Terminal Font.

Here is my code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Code,Name,Price", con);
SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C://test.txt")) {

while (read.Read()) 
{
    //Code
    string CodeString = (read["Code"].ToString());
    sw.Write(CodeString);

    //Name
    string NameString = (read["Name"].ToString());
    sw.Write(NameString);

    //Price
    string PriceString = (read["Price"].ToString());
    sw.Write(PriceString);
}

sw.Close();
read.Close();
```

Comment: A plain text file doesn't contain any formatting info like font, colour, font size, etc. To do that you'd have to export to a rich format like RTF or HTML. To do that Google e.g. `c# sql server export to rtf`

Answer (score 4):

.txt does not contain any formatting. If you want to format your documents, you'll have to use another file format.

Answer (score 1):

A TXT file is just text (ASCII or UTF8 by default) and does not support fonts or other styling (underline, bold, etc)

Probably the simplest format would be to use RTF (Rich Text Format) which does have simpler styling items available, including font, bold, underline, & colors; and is open format with known specifications. Windows 95 and up came with the program *WordPad* which is an RTF editor.

To learn the codes needed, which are made up of escaped codes like C; you can either write a simple file in WordPad (or other program) and then open that file in NotePad (or other text editor). If that is too cumbersome for you, you could try this [RTF Tutorial](http://www.pindari.com/rtf1.html)

Comment: I think it is distracting to bring up ASCII here. The code in the question is already [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtbhzte9(v=vs.110).aspx) UTF-8. In the PC world, text files have seldom been ASCII, the default being IBM437 or similar for MS-DOS, Windows-1252 or similar for Windows, UTF-8 for .NET and Linux. C# source files themselves are UTF-8 unless you work to make them otherwise.

Comment: @TomBlodget  Agreed on possibly distracting. Text files did exist before the PC and were not even limited to what we know as computers